# Why did the first python recursion program did not work?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, edx

I answered this question on edx: Write a program to calculate the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month.

I was able to answer the problem using iterative process but i tried using recursion. I managed to get the recursion problem to work.

My question is why did my first recursion code did not work and produced an infinite loop. 
I am just a beginner just want to improve my knowledge. Thank you very much for helping me

'''
This is my first code
''''

```
def recur(balance,n):
    if n < 1:
        return balance
    else:
        return ((1+monthly_interest_rate)*(recur(balance, n-1)) - (minimumPaymentRate*(recur(balance, n-1)))) balance = 42
annualInterestRate = 0.2
n = 12
minimumPaymentRate = 0.04
monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate/12.0
recur(balance, n)
```

'''
The second code worked
'''

```
def recur(balance,n):
    if n < 1:
        return balance
    else:
        bal_recur = recur(balance, n-1)
        payment_made = (minimumPaymentRate*bal_recur)
        return ((1+monthly_interest_rate)*(bal_recur - payment_made))

balance = 42
annualInterestRate = 0.2
n = 12
minimumPaymentRate = 0.04
monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate/12.0
recur(balance, n)
```

Comment: Works fine for me, albeit with a slightly different result than the second script.
See [here](https://repl.it/repls/CoolNoxiousAccounting). There is a syntax error with the balance variable declaration being on the same line as the function return, but if you were actually using that you would get an error, not an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 1 error in your first code :

```py
def recur(balance,n):
    if n < 1:
        return balance
    else:
        return ((1+monthly_interest_rate)* ( (recur(balance, n-1)) - (minimumPaymentRate*(recur(balance, n-1))) ) ) #here you need to add 2 parenthesis like you do in your second code
balance = 42
annualInterestRate = 0.2
n = 12
minimumPaymentRate = 0.04
monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate/12.0
recur(balance, n)
```